# Authenticate ADFS with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, saml, amazon-cognito, adfs

I am developing Android application which uses AWS as back end. Users can login into the mobile app using ADFS (SAML 2.0) (email and password).

What is the best method to do this and any sample documents that I can refer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a build in functionality with Cognito.

Here is the complete documentation on how to build ADFS with Cognito.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-adfs-federation-for-your-web-app-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [enter link description here](https://gitlab.com/smoghal/cognito-amplify-idp-auth)

Also if you can explain hows your logout flow working ?